# Engine makes ticking noice

Tags: engine

I have a nissan and the engine is making a ticking sound at the underside of the engine. My oil level is good. When idling you can hear the sound but when accelerating the sound disappears. On the left side I can hear the sound very clear and in the right side les. When opening the hood there is no ticking. Your help on what this could be.

Comment: is it only making a sound when your driving? if not i'm confused by what you mean when you say it goes away with the hood opening?

Comment: When the car idles you hear the ticking noice at the bottom of the engine but not on the top of the engine. So when you are trying to listen when the hood is open there is no sound from the top of engine, but from under the car. When accelerating the noice goes away but when driving you can hear it again.